# Admob ads show in emulator or genymotion but not in my device

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, ads

I am working in my app and i add banner ads in all screen that i have in my app when i run it in genymotion it appear very well but when i run it in my device.

samsung ace or samsung s2 it appear only in splashscreen not in other activity 
its show me in logcat ads is not visible not refreshin ad i use the same code of ads  in all activity

[image]

and the same xml file :

[image]

what wrong with that code and thanks

Comment: Show your full xml file

Comment: that's it http://store2.up-00.com/2015-04/1428322172751.png Piyush Gupta

Comment: http://store2.up-00.com/2015-04/1428322172852.png

Comment: all my xml file contain listview or web view with ads view

Comment: Post your logcat here. Post your full layout here. Post your code here.